# Rolled to his feet - meaning

Tags: meaning

> He was sitting on the floor with his back against the wall.
> ...He **rolled to his feet** like a snake raising its head on its body to strike.

It's a quote from the book. I suppose it means the same as "stood up" . Is that correct or does it differ somehow?

Comment: The end result is that he’s standing. Yes.  But I am having a hard time picturing how it could happen as described.

Comment: I shouldn't think it's meant to be taken as a literal descrip[tion, more a suggestion that he's dangerous and is ready

Comment: If you're sitting on the floor with your legs in front of you and knees bent you can kind of "roll" your whole body forward and up at the same time, as compared to standing straight up without forward movement by first moving your feet under you. But I don't think it makes sense to describe the action as both "rolling" and "like a snake raising its head", the two don't go together.

Comment: Tweedle-dum/dee could probably do it. **He reared up** would be more plausible though. Maybe that's what he/she meant.

Comment: Maybe it means that he sort of slithered to his feet, since a snake is evoked.

Comment: 1. Sit on the floor with your back against a wall; 2. rotate your right shoulder and upper body in an anti-clockwise direction; 3. place your left hand on the floor to support yourself; 4. when able, stand up - you have rolled to your feet.

Comment: It seems you can't reply to a certain person, so thank you all! Apparently it doesn't seem like a common phrase at all so I'm gonna stick with "stood up".